# How 2 dynamic (external) IP devices can talk to each other via 1 static (external) IP

Tags: nat, tcp, udp, forwarding

I have 3 devices:

- Device 1 (Dynamic IP): A raspberry Pi sending UDP packets to Device 2 via 4G modem via Internet
- Device 2 (Static IP): My Ubuntu/Windows PC with static IP, successfully receives packets from Device 2 by using NAT port
- Device 3 (Dynamic IP): Now I want another computer to connect to Device 2 (by TCP???) to take the stream (whole packets) from Device 1.

How can I implement this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could configure your fixed IP host as OpenVPN server and the rest of machines as OpenVPN clients